# callback = callback || function() {};

Tags: javascript, callback

What is the purpose of the above line of code. I'm specifically confused by OR-ing the 'function() {}'. Why the empty function? To give a little more context to the line of code, here is the more complete function definition.

```
this.detectQRCode = function(imageData, callback) {

     callback = callback || function() {};

     client.decode(imageData, function(result) {
       if(result !== undefined) {
         self.currentUrl = result;
       }
       callback(result);
     });
};
```

Comment: This is the same as `if (!callback) callback = function() {};`. I.e. it defines _fallback_ value

Comment: It means if callback function exists then execute that callback or simply do nothing by executing exmpty function...

Comment: If no callback assign `function() {}` so that the later execution of `callback` doesn't throw error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is just a "short circuit" coding style. It is checking to ensure that callback isn't undefined. If it is undefined, then it is assigning it an anonymous function in order for the callback() code to not fail.

It is equivalent to

```
if(typeof(callback) == "undefined") callback = function(){};
```

A pitfall of this approach is that if callback is defined, but is not a function, then using `callback()` on something which cannot be called will cause an error. It would be best to use

```
if(toString.call(callback) != "[object Function]") callback = function(){};
```